# how is it possible to make a jtextarea scrollable in gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, gridbaglayout, scrollable

together . this is the first time iam looking for help.

in java, swing, gridbaglayout i generate a form with multiple fields.

If the form comes up, all fields are visible with 1 row.
an when a field gets the focus, and is typ of JTextarea it grows to multiple rows.

All this is working fine,
but i need the multipleRowField **scrollable**.
When the focus is lost the field should have ony 1 row.

the last try was to put the txtfield in a panel...

i read the web empty, but i cant find a solution.
maybe i made a simple mistake. im hopefull that annyone has an idea

i will show you my testcode:

**first file**

```
   code   

 package Dynamicgridbag;

 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
 import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;
 import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
 import javax.swing.border.Border;
 import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
 import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

 import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

public class main {
private static final Border emtyborder = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            System.err.println("Change in " + e.getSource());
            System.err.println("Vertical visible? " + 
 scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible());
            System.err.println("Horizontal visible? " + 
 scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().isVisible());
        }
    });
    // panel.add(scrollPane);
    buildBasicDetailGrid(panel);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

private static void buildBasicDetailGrid(JPanel anchorPanel) {
    //
    // ------------------------ GridBag------------------------------
    //

    anchorPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints constrains = new GridBagConstraints();

    int rows = 10;
    //
    // define basic grid count of fields (for every column one Row and one NullRol
    //
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows * 2 + 2; i += 2) {
        constrains.gridx = 0;
        constrains.gridy = i;
        JLabel blindYLabel = new JLabel("     ");
        blindYLabel.setBorder(emtyborder);

        blindYLabel.setBackground(Color.black);
        blindYLabel.setEnabled(false);
        // blind.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,25));
        if (i > 0) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                blindYLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 5));
                blindYLabel.setMaximumSize(blindYLabel.getPreferredSize());
                blindYLabel.setBackground(Color.black);
            } else {
                blindYLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 5));
                blindYLabel.setMaximumSize(blindYLabel.getPreferredSize());
                blindYLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
        }
        blindYLabel.setOpaque(true);
        anchorPanel.add(blindYLabel, constrains);
    }
    //
    // define basic grid count of Label + gap + field + gap + unit + gap ...
    //
    int cols = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
        constrains.gridx = i;
        constrains.gridy = 0;
        JLabel blindXLabel = new JLabel("     ");
        blindXLabel.setBorder(emtyborder);
        blindXLabel.setBackground(Color.black);
        blindXLabel.setEnabled(false);
        blindXLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 25));
        blindXLabel.setOpaque(true);
        anchorPanel.add(blindXLabel, constrains);
    }
    //
    GridBagConstraints constrain = new GridBagConstraints();

    for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= cols; c++) {
            if (c == 1 || c == 5) {
                constrain.gridx = c;
                constrain.gridy = r + 1;
                constrain.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
                JButton button = new JButton("   button   " + r + c);
                anchorPanel.add(button, constrain);
            }
        }
    }
    //
    GridBagConstraints txtconstrains = new GridBagConstraints();
    //
    txtconstrains.weighty = 1;
    //
    for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= cols; c++) {
            if (c == 3) {
                txtconstrains.gridx = c;
                txtconstrains.gridy = r + 1;
                txtconstrains.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

                String text = "text " + r + c;

                JTextArea txtfld = new JTextArea(text);
                JPanel dummypanel = new JPanel();
                JScrollPane txtfld_scroll = new JScrollPane(txtfld);
                txtfld_scroll.add(txtfld);
                dummypanel.add(txtfld_scroll, txtconstrains);

                //
                txtfld_scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(txtfld_scroll.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                txtfld_scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(txtfld_scroll.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                //
                Dimension txtdim = new Dimension();
                txtdim.width = 330;
                txtdim.height = 20; // alt 32

                txtfld.setSize(txtdim);
                txtfld.setPreferredSize(txtdim);
                txtfld.setMinimumSize(dummypanel.getPreferredSize());

                txtfld.addFocusListener(new GridFieldListener(anchorPanel, txtconstrains));
                anchorPanel.add(txtfld, txtconstrains);
                // anchorPanel.add(txtfld_scroll, txtconstrains);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**second file**

```
   code   

 package Dynamicgridbag;

 import java.awt.Component;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
 import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
 import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

 import java.beans.*;
 import java.time.LocalDate;
 import java.time.ZoneId;
 import java.util.Date;

 //public class GridFieldListener implements PropertyChangeListener, Runnable
 public class GridFieldListener implements FocusListener, Runnable {

private String oldValue = "";
private String newValue = "";
private Object gridfield = null;
private JPanel panel = null;
private GridBagConstraints gbc = null;

public GridFieldListener(JPanel panel, GridBagConstraints gbc) {
    this.panel = panel;
    this.gridfield = gridfield;
    this.gbc = gbc;
}

public GridFieldListener() {

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    System.out.println("buildGridUnit focusGained FocusEvent: " + e);
    gridfield = e.getComponent();
    gridfield = e.getSource();
    System.out.println("focusGained focusGained e.getSource(): " + e.getSource());
    //
    if (gridfield instanceof JTextArea) {
        JTextArea txtarea = (JTextArea) gridfield;
        System.out.println("focusGained focusGained txtarea: " + txtarea);

        Dimension olddim = txtarea.getSize();
        System.out.println("focusGained focusGained olddim: " + olddim);
        double oldheigh = olddim.getHeight();
        double oldwidth = olddim.getWidth();
        double newheigh = oldheigh * 4;
        double newwidth = oldwidth;
        Dimension newdim = new Dimension();
        newdim.setSize(newwidth, newheigh);
        System.out.println("focusGained focusGained newdim: " + newdim);

        txtarea.setSize(newdim);
        txtarea.setPreferredSize(newdim);

        //
        txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText());
        //
        // panel.repaint();
        txtarea.repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    System.out.println("buildGridUnit focusLost FocusEvent: " + e);

    //
    if (gridfield instanceof JTextArea) {
        JTextArea txtarea = (JTextArea) gridfield;

        Dimension olddim = txtarea.getSize();
        System.out.println("focusGained focusGained olddim: " + olddim);
        double oldheigh = olddim.getHeight();
        double oldwidth = olddim.getWidth();
        double newheigh = oldheigh / 4;
        double newwidth = oldwidth;
        Dimension newdim = new Dimension();
        newdim.setSize(newwidth, newheigh);
        System.out.println("focusGained focusGained newdim: " + newdim);
        txtarea.setSize(newdim);
        txtarea.setPreferredSize(newdim);

        txtarea.repaint();


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add the component to a `JScrollPane`, then add the scroll pane to the panel with grid bag layout using an appropriate constraint.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. Please [edit] the question to add 4 space chars ahead of the closing `}` at the end of the code. 3) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 3) `JTextArea txtfld = new JTextArea(text);` Use the variant  that ..

Comment: .. specifies columns and rows to give the scroll pane and layout manager better hints on how to size the text area.